# Collecting every txt file from computer in python and printing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, operating-system, txt

I am trying to collect every txt file from my computer and write it into the terminal when I run the script. I do not know how to do it. Is there a way to read every txt file in the computer then print the contents? (not a certain folder or directory).

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What does "collect" mean?  What is the definition of a text file?  Do you mean display or actually print it?  On linux `find / -name \*.txt| xargs cat` would be the way I do it.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the `glob` module would give you a list of filenames matching a given string.  In your case, `glob.glob('dir/*.txt')` would give you a list of filenames in directory `dir` that end in .txt.  You can then open each file and `print()` it to the terminal.  Depending on your OS, you might be able to do it in your terminal without writing a separate script.